# Iframe to infinity

Tags: html, iframe

If I have an HTML page, and in it I have an iframe that loads the page the iframe is on within it...

What will happen?

Comment: Why not try out? http://jsfiddle.net/tze8x/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nothing will happen due to restrictions. (the browser ain't -that- stupid anymore)

Comment: Pah. This is boring. I expect at least a space-time distortion of some sort.

Comment: Did crazy things happen on older browsers?  Would it work in IE6?

Comment: I think that is the first (or second) thing that came to mind when they designed the IFrame/Ilayer. so no. Recursion of IFrames in IFrames is even limited to 10? so it would stop at 10? in the worst case.

Comment: @Pekka, perhaps a kitten is killed, but we would never know.

Comment: @Pekka using IE you can as usually get that delivered as ordered, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

For most browsers - as in Mozilla, Webkit et al. - nothing will happen because eventually there is a limit on the iframe nesting depth. Also any iframe with its SRC being set to the exact URL used by one of its parents will be treated to have no SRC URL at all (the iframe renders as a blank frame - as shown in the fiddle from the above comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tze8x/1/).

BUT for Internet Explorer different rules apply... If you add a simple iteration number as a query string to the nested iFrame's src IE - and we also tested this with the latest IE version 10 - just crashes :)

**this.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="this.php?q=<?php echo (isset($_GET['q'])?$_GET['q']:1)+1?>" />
</body>
</html>
```