# Is there a limitation on an IFRAME containing another IFRAME with the same URL?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

In order to play around a bit with frame hierarchy I wrote a small html page which allows nesting an arbitrary number of frames (code available at the end of the question).

However this doesn't work, on IE9 and Firefox 4 the inner frames are created but aren't rendered (the `head` and `body` are empty):

[image: frames screenshot]

and on Chrome it works for two levels and then if I click the `Add` button on the inner frame nothing happens (no error message in the console either).

If I copy the file `N` times and have each file use a different file it works for any depth (but not if there's a cycle).

I tried to search for such a limitation but I must not have used the right keywords. Does anyone have any reference for this?

Here's the **addRemoveFrames.html** file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Add and Remove Frames</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function add() {
                var f = document.createElement('iframe');
                f.src = 'addRemoveFrames.html';
                document.getElementById('frameContainer').appendChild(f);
            }
            function remove() {
                var c = document.getElementById('frameContainer');
                var f = c.lastChild;
                if (f)
                    c.removeChild(f);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add"/>
            <input type="button" onclick="remove()" value="Remove"/>
            <hr />
            <div id="frameContainer"></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

---

I've modified [@davin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448296/davin)'s answer slightly so each frame's URL reflects its full path in the hierarchy.

```
var counter = 0;
function add() {
    var f = document.createElement('iframe');
    var sep = location.search ? (location.search + '.') : "?";
    f.src = 'addRemoveFrames.html' + sep + ++counter;
    document.getElementById('frameContainer').appendChild(f);
}
```

Comment: Not voting as dupe because it doesn't answer the question in depth, but related: [iframe to infinity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5763508)

Comment: @Pekka, I'm not sure this is the same thing, I'm not trying to make an infinite recursion by adding the `IFRAME` object itself, I'm creating a new `IFRAME` with the same source (`document.createElement`).

Comment: ah, okay. I *think* it's the same security mechanism at work, though. Interesting.

Comment: That's crazy. It is clearly to not allow an infinite overflow. A workaround that looks to work is by adding a useless query parameter, like `f.src = 'addRemoveFrames.html?id=' + id++;` Strangely though you have to wait a few seconds before adding on new ones for this to work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like a sensible browser security mechanism to prevent an infinite loop of nested iframes (even though in your case it wouldn't be infinite).

In any case, a simple workaround could be to add a useless query parameter to the url, making the browser think the page loaded isn't identical, but really it is.

So instead of your current function `add()`, something like this (I went all out so `id` doesn't polute the global namespace):

```
var add = (function(){

  var id = 0;
  return function(){
     var f = document.createElement('iframe');
     f.src = 'addRemoveFrames.html?useless=' + id++;
     document.getElementById('frameContainer').appendChild(f);
  };

})();
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is an official reference: [Implementing HTML Frames - W3C Working Draft 31-Mar-97](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331).  The heading is 'Infinite Recursion' and states that if the `src` is equal to the parent URL, it should be treated as empty.

I would recommend the technique `davin` uses, or use pure DOM to create nested elements instead of `IFRAME`s, which would make programmatic changes easier and potentially use less memory, as well as avoiding that issue with delayed loading.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if A embeds B which embeds C  which embeds A? In other words would indirect cyclical references crash the browser?

Comment: According to the W3C specs at https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331 "Infinite recursion is prevented. Any frame that attempts to assign as its SRC a URL used by *any of its ancestors* is treated as if it has no SRC URL at all[...]" I would also assume each browser has a hardcoded limit to how many iframes you can nest (for Firefox, this appears to be 10.)

Answer (score 2):

[image: chrome]
I tested it with chrome, the maximum image nesting is 4. inside the second "asd" (red one) is an iframe, but the  is empty

If i include a third page, the nesting increases

[image]

Conclusion: depends in the url, if you have an unlimited amount of nested UNIQUE urls, you can nest indefinitely