# Why does a self-referencing iframe not infinitely loop and crash my machine?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

I created a simple HTML page with an `iframe` whose `src` attribute references the containing page -- in other words a self-referencing iframe.

**this.html**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="this.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does this not infinitely loop and crash my browser?  Also, why doesn't even IE crash at this?

(Note: This spawned from a team discussion on the virtues and demerits of using iframes to solve problems.  You know, the 'mirror of a mirror' sort.)

Comment: Food for thought, this was actually addressed at some point (1999?) but I wonder what the rationale was? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=8065

Comment: This is already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763508/iframe-to-infinity

In short, browsers place limits on iframe nesting.

Comment: Your code was able to break one thing after all. My devtools: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8989748/devtools_broken.png . I hope you are happy now :(

Comment: 1000 points for *"why doesn't even IE crash at this?"*

Answer (score 93, accepted):

W3C took care of that in 1997 explaining how frames should be implemented in "[Implementing HTML Frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331)":

> Any frame that attempts to assign as its SRC a URL used by any of its ancestors is treated as if it has no SRC URL at all (basically a blank frame).

---

### Iframe recursion bug/attack history

As kingdago found out and mentioned in the comment above, one browser that missed to implement a safeguard for this was **Mozilla** in *1999*. Quote from one of the developers:

> This is a parity bug (and a source of possible embarrasment) since MSIE5 
>   doesn't have a problem with these kinds of pages.

I decided to dig some more into this and it turns out that in *2004* this happened [again](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=228829). However, this time **JavaScript** was involved:

> This is the code, what causes it: <iframe name="productcatalog"
>   id="productcatalog"  src="page2.htm"></iframe> directly followed by
>   a script with this in it:
>   frames.productcatalog.location.replace(frames.productcatalog.location
>   + location.hash);
>
> ...
>
> Actual Results:   The parent window gets recursively loaded into the
>   iframe, resulting sometimes in a crash.
>
> Expected Results:   Just show it like in Internet Explorer.

Then [again](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/27812/info) in *2008* with **Firefox 2** (this also involved JavaScript).

And [again](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530258) in *2009*. The interesting part here is that this bug is **still open** and this attachment: `https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=414035` (will you restrain your curiosity?) will still crash/freeze your Firefox (I just tested it and I almost crashed the whole Ubuntu). In Chrome it just loads indefinitely (probably because each tab lives in a separate process).

---

As for the other browsers:

- In *2005* [Konqueror](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116406) had a bug in it's safeguard that allowed to render iframes [one inside another](http://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=18978) (but it seems that somehow it wasn't freezing/crashing the whole app).
- IE6, Opera 7.54 and Firefox 0.9.3 are also [reported](http://xforce.iss.net/xforce/xfdb/17089) to be susceptible to attacks basing on iframe recursion.

Comment: You are an amazing person @Konrad

Comment: Well thank you @kingdango. This is a great question, I ended up doing a research on "iframe recursion bug/attack" history, check out my updated answer.

Comment: @Konrad as I illustrated in my answer below an iframe recursion attack should still be possible today with all versions of IE - that is if one can exploit the generic crash I found.

Comment: You can create this behavior in modern browsers, too -- it just requires JavaScript: e.g. `frame.src = 'http://0.0.0.0:9922/index.html?' + new Date().getTime()`

Answer (score 42):

I'd like to add a little something to the *"Also, why doesn't even IE crash at this?"* part of the question. IE does not let us down...

If you add a simple iteration number as a query string to the nested iFrame's src Firefox and others will just stop after a certain iteration depth. IE - and we tested this with IE version 10 - just crashes :)

**this.php**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="this.php?q=<?php echo (isset($_GET['q'])?$_GET['q']:1)+1?>" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I love the person inside you that made you test this.

Comment: I tested on FF 108.0, on the third call of a same URL (with thing after `?`, without thing after `#`) it's empty. Is this "iteration" something else?

Answer (score 3):

IE 6.0 can crash without script:

```html
<iframe src="this.html?c=9"></iframe>
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't trigger loop detection nor if it's changed though.

EDIT: Got the reason. since it's a local file, URL after `?` is ignored, so only `this.html` is marked visited, not `this.html?c=9`.

Comment: Testing stuff on IE 6.0 in 2022 is worth a +1 to me :-)