# Why aren't iframe's recursive?

Tags: html, recursion

Say for example you have an HTML page called `index.html` with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A web page</title>   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A web page<h1>
    <img src="logo.png"/>
    <iframe src="index.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view this page in the browser I was expecting the iframes to form a never ending loop because effectively the page keeps calling itself but I only get one iframe.  Obviously this is good but I was just wondering what prevents this from happening?

**Or** what if you have two webpage on different URL's each had an iframe to the other page.  For example what if the Google homepage had  `<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>` and Facebook's homepage has `<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>`

Comment: See previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223628/why-does-a-self-referencing-iframe-not-infinitely-loop-and-crash-my-machine