# Why iframe is not loaded for same url as page

Tags: html, iframe

I was just testing some stuff and came across the interesting `iframe` behavior.
On the page i have the following `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="/Wizard/Start"></iframe>
```

Now, if the `src` of `iframe` is the same as url of the page `(.../Wizard/Start)`, the `iframe` does not load the contents, just remains blank and there is no errors, warnings or anything reported.

I can see that this is by design, acts the same in all browsers.

Why? Any official documentation on this behavior?

Comment: Try to use some kind of Network profiler, and check what URL is actually loaded (Hit F12 to get to the debugging console)

Comment: No url is loaded, it seems that if browser encounters iframe with url=pageurl just ignores the further processing

Comment: What browser then ? Did you checked the Network debugger ?

Comment: Possibly, the reason for this is to prevent infinite recursion, but I can't find anything official on this subject

Comment: Dude! I have checked and there is no request in any browser, do you understand the english?

Comment: I think that is a fair assumption (blocking recursion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is indeed the specified behaviour. The answer to your question is in this document:

http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-frames-970331

In the section "Infinite Recursion" it says:

> Infinite recursion is prevented. Any frame that attempts to assign as its SRC a URL used by any of its ancestors is treated as if it has
>   no SRC URL at all (basically a blank frame). This doesn't prevent all
>   malicious documents, but it eliminates a troublesome class of them.

The document dates back to 1997 but hasn't been superseded yet, as far as I know.

Comment: Chrome 39 allowed me to use a src with the same url, but IE11 and Firefox 33 didn't.

Comment: Is this design implemented only on Firefox and IE?

Comment: @David, right, but Chrome doesn't allow it inside iframe. In other words, in Chrome, one-level recursion allowed only.

Answer (score 1):

you mean you are loading the iframe of "**abc**" page of **abc** page??

```
_____________________
|                    |
|      IFrame        |
---------------------|
|                    |
|       Page         |
|                    |
_____________________
```

and here iframe again pointing to the same page right?? see it will not work as it become the infinite loop..

you are trying to load the same page in iframe.. mean the content of iframe again contains another iframe which again pointing to the same page which again has the iframe.. so it will be infinite loop and thats why it will not work..

on page **"xyz"** you can include the iframe of **"abc"**, it will not be a problem

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing.

Comment: Anything official on this subject, W3C, .... Like "You are not allowed to put src on iframe same as origin url", or something like this?

Comment: i dont know.. but i got your scenario thats why told you.. and told u the reason why its not displaying..well i found another stackoverflow example for your check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223628/why-does-a-self-referencing-iframe-not-infinitely-loop-and-crash-my-machine   this is what i told you..