# Firefox not loading iframe content

Tags: firefox, iframe, web, same-origin-policy

I have a page at http://localhost/page1
and On that page i am showing http://localhost/page2 content in an iframe in some div.

It works fine in chrome. However in firefox, page2 does not show up.
I don't get any warnings/error in firefox console.

Since both the pages have same domain. firefox should correctly load page2 iframe

Am i missing something obvious?

Comment: same issue here - same protocol, same domain, no errors in console. but loading not happening

Answer (score 1):

It is purposefully loads an empty iframe.  This happens in Firefox to prevent infinite recursion.

According to the W3C specification on frames:

> Infinite recursion is prevented. Any frame that attempts to assign as
>   its SRC a URL used by any of its ancestors is treated as if it has no
>   SRC URL at all (basically a blank frame). This doesn't prevent all
>   malicious documents, but it eliminates a troublesome class of them.

Please see the attached stackoverflow article - this is where I found the answer.

[Infinite recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126190/why-iframe-is-not-loaded-for-same-url-as-page/22126386#22126386)